# Recreate orders from woocommerce order confirmations

Tags: woocommerce

is there any way to recreate orders on woocommerce using only the order confirmations that woocommerce sent to the seller? Copy paste is an option but this would mean that the order numbers are created anew and I would love to have them with their original order numbers. Is there also a mapping file that can be found in woocommerce so order informations can be pasted on there?

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Manually copying the orders from the confirmations :(

Comment: Is your WooCommerce site a marketplace? Why do you want that? Try to better explain things, editing question, with all the necessary details. What does mean *"Is there also a mapping file that can be found in woocommerce so order informations can be pasted on there?"*?